# Указать версию приложения

Tags: c#, blazor, version

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо указать **версию приложения** `blazor` на главной странице (например в левом верхнем углу) (сервер `IIS`)

Есть вопросы :

- как узнать что какая цифра значит
- как правильно вести счет, настраивать или писать в ручную каждый раз
- есть ли правила например в СиШарп так то делают
- надо ли год добавлять
- в приложении или на сервере делать
- как искать (инфу, док), что вбивать в поиск гугла
- и может еще есть ответы...

нашла только вот такую [статью](https://unetway.com/blog/numeracia-versij-programmnogo-obespecenia), то что я поняла это

`мажор, минор и стадия разработки` это значение цифр(букв). Ок, а как и куда копать, чтоб понять ответы на вопросы выше. Не может же быть, что статически меняют просто цифры ?

**в поиске что вписать**? Я пишу (указать версию приложения/ версия приложения/ version aplication итп) и каждый раз выходит информация про нугет пакеты, про версии приложений...

нашла только вот [на стекОверФлоу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70855789/displaying-the-version-in-an-asp-net-core-blazor-project-set-from-azure-devops) вопрос, но это как на ДевАзуре настроить. **А может есть настройки для IIS** ?

Comment: Это информация, которая по большей части нужна авторам проекта, по которой они понимают что, когда, как было добавлено/изменено, и так далее. Большинство придерживаются правилам [Семантического Версионирования](https://semver.org/lang/ru/), но есть проекты, где придумывают свои внутренние правила.

Comment: Я лично использую в своих проектах старое доброе автоматическое версирование от Microsoft, для этого просто указываю `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` (правда в .NET с этим гемор, решение для FW), после чего, при сборке версия будет выглядеть примерно так `1.0.3266.92689`, что расшифровывается в `01.01.2000 + 3266 дней + 92689 * 2 сек`, получится `1.0 +` конкретная дата и время билда. Остается отправить это в `DevOps` например для автосборки и публикации проекта, и готово, у нас не просто циферки, а полезная информация.

Comment: *просто указываю [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]* , А где указываете @EvgeniyZ ? в PropertyGroup? что такое *решение FW* ? а если не ДевОпс а IIS

Comment: дело в том, что на ДевОпс я не смогла разобраться как сборку сделать и поэтому приложение на IIS, так оказалось легче как для меня. Конечно на ДевОпс наверно правильней, но на сегодня я доступ даю пользователям с IIS, и там как вы и отметили эта версия для меня(них), чтоб после ремарк знать, что обновить и потом версию показать следующую

Comment: `А где указываете?` - ПКМ по проекту, добавить,  информационный файл сборки, будет создан файл `AssemblyInfo.cs`, в который и пишете все нужное (на всякий проверьте свойства проекта, чтоб этот файл был указан там). В .NET этот файл генерируется автоматически, и будет конфликт, чтоб этого не было, надо убрать авто. генерацию, но это думаю быстро найдете сами. `что такое решение FW ` - .NET Framework, старая версия .NET, в которой достаточно прописать в файле и все.

Comment: `а если не ДевОпс а IIS` - это две разные вещи, где DevOps набор инструментов по тестированию, сборки, публикации проекта (я пользуюсь бесплатным от [Microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/devops)), ну а IIS это сервер, который условно обрабатывает входящие запросы. и переадресовывает их вашему приложению) Через DevOps я обычно делаю такую цепочку: 1. Отправляю в Git исправление. 2. Это исправление автоматически тестируется в облаке. 3. После успешного тестирования устанавливается автоматически версия и собирается проект. 4. После сборки, проект публикуется на сервере.

Comment: ПКМ-это правКликМышкой, ок а [информационный файл ? это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMAh3.png) => `New Editor Config` ?

Comment: Смотрите по названию файла, если он `AssemblyInfo.cs`, то это то, что вам нужно. Кстати, этот файл уже может быть в вашем проекте, будьте внимательней.

Comment: [по названию файла вбила в поиск и вот что вышло](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138418/equivalent-to-assemblyinfo-in-dotnet-core-csproj)

Comment: Да, как и сказал выше, в .NET идет автоматическая генерация этих атрибутов, из-за чего идет их дублирование. Тут либо оставлять автоматизацию, либо переписывать файл, добавляя туда только нужное, выключив авто. генерацию. А, там еще надо `<Deterministic>false</Deterministic>` указать в `.csproj`

Comment: оставлю тут [там как раз про Deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782085/assemblyversion-using-fails-with-error-wildcards-which-are-not-compatible-wi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@EvgeniyZ в комментариях дал информацию и ответил на вопросы. Я прошлась по ссылкам из названия файла, почитала как делают другие/посмотрела что такое версия **в общем и целом**, и для себя решила этот вопрос следующим образом⏬, *возможно в дальнейшем я изменю этот способ, но на сегодня просто*

...Так как `программист` (*я пока не вдавалась в подробности настроек, чтоб проект сам обновлял*) решает какую `цифру` и когда менять в версии, поэтому я буду менять это в ручную при сборке.
то есть `Мажор, Минор, и стадии разработки`.

Прописываю версию я в самом проекте
`to project -> properties`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тут же в файле `.csproj` появляется тег `<Version>1.0.1</Version>`

**затем, чтоб вывести это на страницу**⏬, *я например добавила в футер мелким шрифтом, чтоб было видно на каждой странице, и например пользователя спросить какая версия у вас, и обновить при необходимости* (`publish`)

```html
<span>@versionApp</span>
```

```
 @using System.Reflection;

 System.Version? appVersion { get; set; }
 string versionApp { get; set; }
```

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
........
    if (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version != null)
    {
        appVersion = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
        versionApp = String.Format("V{0}", appVersion);
    }
........
}
```

[по этой ссылке есть информация по каждому атрибуту](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets)